# Regex searching isNULL()

Tags: regex

I have problem with regex. 
How find a regular `"isNULL(X)="`
X is everythink 
number of "(" and ")" must be the same...

```
isNULL[\s]*[(]+[here is problem] [)]+[\s]*[=]+
```

example

```
good asdasd isNULL(some(some2(some3),some5)-some6(),some(7)) = 
bad isNULL())=
```

Comment: post ur attempts , take a search regarding `(?R)`

Comment: what is the language?

Comment: If I understand it right, you can't use a regex to do this. You have to use a parser for what ever language you are in.

Comment: Not for every language. What is the regex flavor (library)/language?

Comment: i trying do that in C# but i must use in SQL

Comment: In SQL, you mean TSQL? I can only suggest a .NET regex (http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=isNULL%5Cs*%5C((%3F%3E%5B%5E()%5D%7C(%3F%3Cc%3E%5C()%7C(%3F%3C-c%3E%5C)))*(%3F(c)(%3F!))%5C)%5Cs*%3D&i=good+asdasd+isNULL(some(some2(some3)%2Csome5)-some6()%2Csome(7))+%3D+%0D%0Abad+isNULL())%3D+). In TSQL, regex is not supported at all.

Comment: Here is a [link](https://www.myregextester.com/?r=3a6a13fe).